# CCJumpBy on a sprite

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

These are my first Cocos2D projects, I'm trying to make a sprite jump in the same place **when touched**, but I can't make it response because I don't know how to set touch actions on sprites.
Here is the code :

```
-(void) spriteEffect
{
    CCSprite *actionEffect = avatar;
    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:2];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: jump, nil];
    [actionEffect runAction:sequence];

    return yes
}
```

Should I use a

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you show more code? is the sprite part of a scene? show how you create it and add to a scene.

Comment: well, what is avatar? where do you create it and add it to your scene?

Comment: avatar is an array of sprites,here:
       -(BOOL)isAvatarSelected:(int)idToSelect
       -(void)selectAvatar:(CCMenuItemImage*)sender

Comment: `runAction` can be executed on a single sprite, not on a array of sprites... this explain why the action is not working.

Comment: Great job! is there a way to do this in all my sprites?

Comment: what kind of array is `avatar`? NSArray? C array?

Comment: ok, see my answer... it should work.

Comment: sorry, it was a ccsprite only, my bad... what should i do?

Comment: go back to my first comment.

Comment: I work with a .plist of that sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment that `avatar` is an array of sprites helps clarifying why you don't see any effects. Try to do something like:

```
-(void) spriteEffect
{
 CCSprite *actionEffect = <get a sprite from avatar array>;
 id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:2];
 [actionEffect runAction:jump];
```

}

I don't know what kind of array `avatar` is, so I can't provide syntax for accessing its elements. If `avatar` is an `NSArray`, you can make all of your sprites jump by using:

```
-(void) spriteEffect
{
   foreach (CCSprite* actionEffect in avatar) {
     id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:2];
     [actionEffect runAction:jump];
   }
```

}

Comment: I have done the first method, but i have to implement it into the array when I touch it.. that's what i cant do

Comment: I cannot understand clearly what you are doing: what are you doing with a plist? what do you mean: i have to implement it into the array when I touch it? could you elaborate more clearly so that i can try and help?

Comment: Sorry. I have a .plist where I declared the avatars of my sprite (my .png file) I pick the avatar I want from there, and i implement it in the main method.

Comment: please, show how you implement the avatar in the main method... without some code to review, I am doing guess work...