# How to implement an action into a CCSprite in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm trying to implement this method :

```
-(void) SpriteThouch
{
    CCSprite *actionEffect = avatar;
    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:1];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions: jump, nil];
    [actionEffect runAction:sequence];
}
```

into a sprite with characters, i'm utilizing a **.png** that has all the characters in it, and utilize a **.plist** to select each one of them.
My problem is that I can't find the way to make the characters jump when I touch them once. The jumping method works, but when I'm trying to implement it into the touch action it doesn't do anything.
I've being trying this methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 1)
    {
        CCSprite *actionEffect = avatar;
        id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position: ccp(0, 0) height:50 jumps:1];
        id sequence = [CCSequence actions: jump, nil];
        [actionEffect runAction:sequence];
    }
}
```

---

and

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector (SpriteThouch:)] autorelease];
[gr setNumberOfTapsRequired: 1];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

can you help me? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CCJumpBy on a sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462623/ccjumpby-on-a-sprite)

Comment: yes it does, because I'm with the same problem and some people wont look it. Sorry. Anyway, my problem now is that the touch on the sprite doesnt work. Cuando toco el sprite no salta...

Comment: Just to double check, have you set self.touchEnabled = YES; ?

Comment: posting the same question again and again to solicit attention is not good behaviour on stackoverflow. if you edit an old question, it goes automatically on top of the "interesting questions" list so it gets visibility.

Comment: @Mikael mmmmmm I guess not. Where should I put it?

Comment: @sergio Sorry for that, I'm new that's why. Thanks for the advice.-

Comment: Add it to your layer in the init method.

Comment: @Mikael Could you please put an answer with the correct method (cause I put to in my question) and implement it ?

Comment: @Vergmort what do you mean? I suppose you're having an init method in your class.

Comment: @Vergmort Just to be extra clear. If you start a new project with Cocos2d you will get a class named 'HelloWorldLayer.m". If you have your sprite in that class you could add 'self.touchEnabled = YES;' in the '-(id) init'-method of that class.